# Java SpringBoot query 3 tables and return result in json

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oop, jpa

I am new to spring, sql world and would love if someone can help me here.

I have three tables which are

Table1
-id, appName, version, education ,region

Table2
-id, appName, status, subjects, result

Table3
-id, appName, type, state, sports

Note:

id: primary key

appName: unique key

I want to create a controller where request body is "region", "status" and I want to return json of appName,status,version,type,version,region.

How can I achieve the same in springboot.

I was thinking to extend crudRepository but not able figure out the query to use and implementation part.

PS:Thank you in advance.

Comment: What about using a single Query with joins and apply it with @Query annotation in JpaRepository?

Comment: @SaurabhSingh  I am thinking to use this approach and store the result in DTO and then return the json, but issue I am facing is when we extend JpaRepository<T,L> we need to provide a single entity but need 3 tables to perform join here. How can I use/extend  JpaRepository for 3 tables. can you help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can try with Spring Data projection or Constructor expression. Create a custom POJO/Interface with all required atributes. For more details https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-queries-custom-result-with-aggregation-functions

Answer (score 0):

You should have one entity which is going to contains Table1, Table2, table3 data.

Use hibernate to join the table with all tables.

Example.

```
@Entity
Class Table1 {
   @Id
   Long id;
   String appName;
   ...
}
@Entity
Class Table2 {
   @Id
   Long id;
   String appName;
   ...
}

@Entity
Class Table3 {
   @Id
   Long id;
   String appName;
   ...
}

@Entity
Class MainObject {
   @Id
   Long id;
   @OneToOne
   Table1 table1;
   @OneToOne
   Table2 table2;

   ...
}
```

Use main object to use curdRepository

Note: use mapping based on your requirements. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_or_mappings.htm

Suggestion: you can add app name to main object as it is repetitive in all tables

Comment: Can I avoid making a new Entity ?

I was thinking to get values from table 1 , then loop each record and retrieve result  from table 2  and so on . This way I would need to create 3 files extend crudRepository<Table1,P_K> like this.

is this possible  or it is a bad design?

Comment: So think like this way. You needs to buy 3 things from market. If you buy in 3 round it might take you 3 hours. But if you bring everything at first place you are saving 2 hours. Same goes with network calls. You are planing to make 3 calls to Database.

Comment: yeah makes sense! will look how can I implement the same . Thank you